# jQuery datepicker z-index not working

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am displaying two frames in a framset control. First frame has datepicker control. When i click the Calendar control the jQuery Datepicker is displaying with in the Frame1 itself. But i need to display the datepicker as popup window. Please help. Thank you.[image: z-index not working jQuery Datepicker]

```
beforeShow: function () {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.ui-datepicker').css('z-index', 99999999999999);
                        $('.ui-datepicker').css('position', 'absolute');
                    }, 0);
                }
```

And this one.

```
    beforeShow': function(input, datepicker) {
setTimeout(function() {
  $(datepicker.dpDiv).css('z-index', 10000);
}, 500);
```

}

And this one.

```
.txtDate{position: relative; z-index:100;}
```

Above codes not working for me. I'm using IE8 browser.

Comment: use `!important` rule

Comment: I tried with !Important rule also, but not working for me.

Comment: .ui-datepicker { z-index:9999 !important;) .ui-datepicker { z-index:9999 !important; poisition:absolute !Important; } div.ui-datepicker{z-index:100 !important; } , .ui-datepicker-calendar
{{z-index:100 !important; position:absolute !Important; },  I have tried all these code separately. None is working.